How to make this page mobile friendly?
This is the background logo.The 3 title images of GTA don't go into a single column at 768px width with a media query setting them to be a grid with just 1 column. I did this before with success but here it's not working.


.body {
  margin-top:0pt;
  margin-left:0pt;
  margin-right:0pt;
  margin-bottom:0pt;
}
                                               
}

.item {
  font-family: "Freeman", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: rgb(2, 1, 0);
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.gta3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 600px;
  top:200px;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Pricedown Bl', sans-serif;  
  font-size:60px;
  text-shadow: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  display:block;
}

.gtavicecity {
  position: relative;
  left: 110px;
  top: -70px;
  color: rgb(221, 71, 221);
  font-family: 'Rage Italic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 90px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.gtasanandreas {
  position:relative;
  left: 1000px;
  bottom:300px;
  font-family: 'Beckett', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  color:black;
  width: 200px;
  display:block;

}

.alsoflexbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  font-family: "Freeman", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color:grey;
  border-radius: 30px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.kezdo {
  font-family: "Freeman", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;

}

@media (max-width: 768px)
{
  .container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;}
    
    .item {
      font-family: "Freeman", sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: rgb(2, 1, 0);
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

}
.gta3 {
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Pricedown Bl', sans-serif;  
  font-size:60px;
  text-shadow: 20px;
  width: 200px;

}

.gtavicecity {
  color: rgb(221, 71, 221);
  font-family: 'Rage Italic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 90px;
  width: 200px;
}

.gtasanandreas {
  font-family: 'Beckett', sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  color:black;
  width: 200px;

}
.gta {
  background-image: url('https://i.sstatic.net/MTcDoSpB.png');
  background-position:center;
}
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"><a class="gta3" href="https://www.gta.fandom.com" style="text-decoration:none;">Grand Theft Auto III</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a class="gtavicecity" href="https://www.gta.fandom.com" style="text-decoration:none;">Vice City</a></div>
        <div class="item"><a class="gtasanandreas" href="https://www.gta.fandom.com" style="text-decoration:none;">San Andreas</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="alsoflexbox">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black" href="zene.html"><div>Zene</div></a> 
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black" href="gta.html"><div>GTA</div></a> 
        <a  style="text-decoration: none;color:black"href="gitár.html"><div>Gitár</div></a> 
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black"href="számítógép.html"><div>Számítógép</div></a> 
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black"href="fotózás.html"><div>Fotózás</div></a> 
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black"href="utazas.html"><div>Utazásaim</div></a> 
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black"href="sport.html"><div>Sport</div></a> 
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black"href="kepesiteseim.html"><div>Képesítéseim</div></a> 
        <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black"href="valami.html"><div>Valami</div></a> 
        </div>
        <div class="kezdo"> <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black" href="index.html">Kezdőoldal</a>
        </div>
</body>



I used a media query and probably many useless code lines. I don't know why my 3 logos don't go in a single column when I reduce the screen size. I could successfully make my other page mobile-friendly using 1 column with a grid and don't know why it doesn't work here.

can you please more information about the issue. also i can't find a class with class name gta in the html section.
